# Any real life example of what happens to something when it is not differentiable at any point?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, applications

Can somebody tell any real life example which explains when something is not differentiable at some point. Like, a car moves and we get a graph of position time function, but what actually happens to that car if that function is not differentiable when time=5? Like is the car still moving or what happens to it? thanks

Comment: The car all of a sudden goes from $30$ mph to $50$ mph

Comment: The car smashes into a wall.

Comment: The standard model for Brownian motion isn't differentiable.  Constantantly accelerating and suddenly beaking at random times.